# Sum of product as product of sums

Tags: variance, covariance, covariance-matrix, approximation

Assuming I have two random non-independent vectors $A,B$ which are within [-1,1]. I want to approximate their sum of product by product of sums (everything is a dot product), i.e.

$\sum_{i=1}^NA_iB_i \approx \sum_{i=1}^NA_i \sum_{i=1}^N B_i$

I can see that this approximation is more and more better if the covariance between the two is closer to zero from the following formula

$Cov(XY) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$

How do I achieve this without destroying any signal in $A,B$? I am only interested in sample estimate of covariance, i.e. even if reducing the sample size or centering and scaling helps to reduce the absolute value of covariance, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You arrived at the [definition of independence of random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Expectation_and_covariance) on your own, congratulations! One formulation is 
$$E[AB]=E[A]E[B]$$
This is true when variables are independent of each other (not the other way around though).

You can't expect your approximation to be good if the variables are not independent or correlated.

Comment: Yes, however, I don't have independent random variables and I need to approximate the sum of product by product of sums, any pointers?

Comment: Moreover, I don't need to exact equivalence, just an approximation (with an error ofcourse)

Comment: @lvdp, you can't always get what you wanted, but if you try, sometimes, you can get what you need. So, why exactly do you need this approximation?

Comment: I am working on a problem where I need to sum individual vectors first and perturb them before I take their product and compare them to perturbing the sum of product, hope I am making some sense. I was thinking about centering, scaling, and standardizing as that will reduce the covariance without destroying much signal, which something like PCA might do.

Comment: perturbation is from Normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$, where $\sigma$ is always >0. Goal of perturbing is to make the vectors noisy and see how the noise impacts the model outcome (model is a neural network).

Comment: I'm trying to preserve whatever signal is in $A,B$. i.e. the product is used for model updates(similar to weight updates in every iteration). I was thinking about decorrelation transformations similar to PCA(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Decorrelation_of_n_random_variables), but that might remove any signal in the data.

Comment: @lvdp, adding uncorrelated noise should not destroy signal, it can flood it if $\sigma$ is large. Noise will lower the correlation.

Comment: yes the noise itself will lower the correlation. I however want to minimize it as much as possible after adding noise. So if I do a decorrelation data transform, do you think it will still preserve the signal?

Comment: @lvdp, you can easily do the "decorrelation", of course, however, I'm not aware of the transform for that. It can be done with Cholesky decomposition, perhaps. I'm afraid this will mess up your NN.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am scared of, I think that is what it essentially is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Decorrelation_of_n_random_variables). I think I might just do scaling and standardization as it will decrease the covariance somewhat. Does using a small sample size by any chance impact the absolute value of covariance in a sample? It seems so from the formulation of sample covariance...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89564/discussion-between-lvdp-and-aksakal).